# Is is possible to load profile extension in chromedriver session?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, python-bindings

I develop a program, which checks browser plugin behaviour [ in python & selenium ]. The plugin is a black box to me I just have it installed in browsers.

For example, in Firefox, i've installed it to my profile and force webdriver to open firefox with desired profile. I've made the same witch chrome, and it obviously loads the profile, but not the extension.

```
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\..\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2\\")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\...\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opt)
```

Is there any way how to make this functionallity work? Or is the problem, that the extension are bound to the logged user, not profile of browser?

What I need to do is to execute chrome with specified url, let the plugin to analyze the site and then check plugin's output.

Another problem is that I am not the one who will use the program, so I wouldn't like to start force user to pack crx extenstion (or is there a simple way to this?). My requirments is that thare is one or two items in configuration file, like

> chrome-profile: path/to/profile

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I do the same on my Fedora and OS X - I just create ChromeOptions and `opts.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/path/to/my/profile')` pointing to the profile with the plugin installed and it works